# user.Lookup returns user while user doesn't exist

Tags: macos, go, macos-catalina

I've noticed a strange issue with a simple service in Go that does some user manipulation on macOS.

When deleting a user and then running `user.Lookup` for the deleted user the command, sometimes, will
return the deleted user's information even though from what I can tell the user doesn't exist.

Some code:

Create user:

```golang
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user)
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user, "UserShell", "/bin/bash")
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user, "RealName", user)
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user, "UniqueID", strconv.Itoa(nextID))
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user, "PrimaryGroupID", "20")
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-create", "/Users/"+user, "NFSHomeDirectory", "/Users/"+user)
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-append", "/Users/"+user, "Picture", "/Library/User", "Pictures/Flowers/Lotus.tif")
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-passwd", "/Users/"+user, getUserPassword())
exec.Command("dseditgroup", "-o", "edit", "-t", user, "-a", user, "staff")
exec.Command("createhomedir", "-c", "-u", user)
```

Delete user:

```golang
exec.Command("dscl", ".", "-delete", "/Users/"+user)
utils.DeleteDir("/Users/" + user)
```

Comment: You're not showing the `user.Lookup` call or any output. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And don't forget to check for errors.

Comment: What I gather from the commands you have shown (and searching the 'net for `man dscl`), the `dscl` command manipulates the "directory services" which, I gather, is some sort of LDAP DB. If yes, _and_ your program was built "the normal way"—that is, to make use of system APIs for user lookup,—a call to `os.Lookup` hits some local facility intended to talk to an LDAP DB server, and such facilities are known to do caching in production setups (as otherwise such systems would be too prone to fail in the presence of networking glitches).

Comment: I have precisely zero working knowledge about macosx in "enterprise" settings, but I'd check this idea first as _intermittent_ failures to notice deleted user look exactly like a caching issue to me.

Comment: It's also unclear how much interaction there is between `dscl` and `/etc/passwd` (which is what `user.Lookup` uses on darwin). Look at the contents of `/etc/passwd` before/after the various commands.

Comment: @Marc, are you sure it does not call out to somthing like `getpwnam(3)` (or whatever macosx might have in place of that)? On *nix, by default, user lookup goes to the system API (usually `libc`) for that. To defeat that, you have to build the program with `cgo` disabled.

Comment: I'm not certain at all, I was mentioning it because it's not clear and could be the issue. But as is, we really can't tell.